# jQuery blur event except when clicking a particular div

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
   $("#newGenreTxt").blur(function () {
        $("#txtAddGenreContainer").slideUp();
    });
```

I want to hide the text box if it loses its focus, but the problem is that I want to hide it if a user clicks anywhere but my button:

```
$("#addGenreFinal").click(function () {});
```

So If user clicks the addGenreFinal nothing happens and if it's something else hide the textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `.slideUp()` call to the a click event firing on the document object and then cancel the click if it is called on either the `addGenreFinal` or the `newGenreTxt` elements:

```
//add event handler to hide the `txtAddGenreContainer` element when the document is clicked
$(document).on('click', function () {
    var $tar = $("#txtAddGenreContainer");//UPDATE
    if ($tar.css('display') != 'none') {//UPDATE
        $tar.slideUp();
    }//UPDATE
});

//add event handler to the `addGenreFinal` and `newGenreTxt` elements to stop the click event from bubbling up the document
$('#addGenreFinal, #newGenreTxt').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qrSEn/

Comment: I like your answer but i'm not sure if this way of solving my problem is well optimized, because I will be clicking all over the place (document) and with every click this function will execute (the first one, the slide up one) so can it affect my performance? Even when the textbox will be hidden, this code will hide it again and again...

Comment: The `slideUp()` function won't run if the element is already hidden, but you can check for that yourself as well. See the **update** to my answer.

Comment: doesn the if statement help with anything, because it is still checking the hidden property everytime i click on the document, it still uses the cumputation power, maybe it's negligible but still..

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, click events propagate.  Unless you call `e.stopPropataion()` from your click handler, it'll still execute click on other objects (like, the document body, for example).

Your logic is flawed anyway as it needs to live at the highest event level and test for what actually started the click event by using `e.target`.

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'addGenreFinal')
        return;
    $('#txtAddGenreContainer').slideUp();
});
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eXhfw/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I would like to know if I could use the brur method and somehow combine it with .not jquery method, although i'm not even sure if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use .blur() you can do that :

```
$("#newGenreTxt").blur(function (e) {
    if ($(e.relatedTarget).attr('id') == 'addGenreFinal')
        return;

    $("#txtAddGenreContainer").slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yz5Gh/